# Access list element in R by the value of a separate variable

Tags: r, list

I have a dataframe with two variables of interest: a character variable that is the state abbreviation for each obs, and a region code for each obs.  I also have a list that associates a set of acceptable region codes to each state.

```
df <- data.frame(state=c("AL","CO","DE","TX"), region=c(1,2,3,4))
acceptable_regions <- list(AL=c(1,2), CO=1, DE=c(2,3), TX=(1:4))
```

I want to create a dummy variable that assigns "0" if the region is included in the set of acceptable codes, and "1" otherwise.
My first thought was to use ifelse() but I get an error that recursive indexing fails at level 2.

```
df$far_away <- ifelse(df$region %in% acceptable_regions[[df$state]], 0,1)
```

I would have thought ifelse would recognize that I want to index through df$state since `acceptable_regions[[df$state[i]]` works on its own.

How can I pull out the list element I want based on the value of the variable "state"?  Trying to avoid for loops of course.

Comment: I had a typo originally.  I just edited CO=1 in the list so that I expect the vector df$far_away to be (0,1,0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the 'state' and corresponding values of 'region' with `map2` (from `purrr`), extract the `list` element of 'acceptable_region' from the value of 'state', check whether it is `%in%` 'region' to get a logical `vector`, coerce it to binary with `as.integer`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(far_away = map2_int(state, region, ~
              as.integer(.y %in% acceptable_regions[[.x]])))
#  state region far_away
#1    AL      1        1
#2    CO      2        0
#3    DE      3        1
#4    TX      4        1
```

---

Or use `rowwise`

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
     mutate(far_away = as.integer(region %in% acceptable_regions[[state]]))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  state region far_away
#  <fct>  <dbl>    <int>
#1 AL         1        1
#2 CO         2        0
#3 DE         3        1
#4 TX         4        1
```

---

Or with `base R`, use `Map`

```
df$far_away <- as.integer(unlist(Map(function(x, y) 
        y %in% acceptable_regions[[x]], df$state, df$region)))
```

Comment: I used the first method you offered with map2.  Simple and effective, thank you!